# Denoting Areas Through "Unions"

Tags: notation

I have the following rectangle:

[image]
How can I denote the areas of $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ using "union" formulas?

For instance, would it be correct to say:

- $C_1 = (A < A_1) \cup (B < B_1)$
- $C_2 = ( A_1 < A < A_2) \cup ( B_1 < B < B_2)$
- $C_3 = ( A_2 < A < A_3) \cup ( B_2 < B < B_3)$

**Is my use of the union correct in these questions?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
C_1=[0,a_1] \times [0,b_1],
$$
$$
C_2 = \left( [0,a_1] \times [b_1,b_2] \right) \cup \left( [a_1,a_2] \times [0,b_2] \right),
$$
$$
C_3 = \left( [0,a_2] \times [b_2,b_3] \right) \cup \left( [a_2,a_3] \times [0,b_3] \right)
$$
might be an option.